# Is there any shortcut to open Python' interactive console with sublimerepl? And if not, can I create one?

Tags: python, sublimerepl

Is there a shortcut to open Ipython from sublimerepl

Comment: [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) hasn't been updated in 7+ years, now. Do you really want to use it, vs VSCode, for example, [which already offers Notebook support?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I use SublimeREPL every day. It doesn't have all the features of using, say, Jupyter, but it works for me, and I like it. And, I don't need to use VSCode :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a shortcut to open the Python interactive console with SublimeREPL. On Windows, the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+C, and on Mac, it is Cmd+Shift+C.

You can also create a custom shortcut by going to the Preferences menu and selecting Keybindings. Then, add a new keybinding with the desired shortcut and the command repl_open, which opens the interactive console. The keybinding should look like this:

```
{ "keys": ["your_shortcut"], "command": "repl_open", "args": {"type": "subprocess", "encoding": "utf8", "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"], "cwd": "$file_path", "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage", "external_id": "python"} }
```

Note that you need to replace "your_shortcut" with the shortcut you want to use.

Comment: This isn't `ipython`, though

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
ctrl+shift+c didn't work but it worked with my custom shortcut.
Ty : )